# Не удается преобразовать из "группа методов" в "Action"

Tags: c#, .net, generics

У меня есть класс `MenuItem`, который отвечает за логику создания новых объектов для меню.

```
public abstract class MenuItem
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        public MenuItem(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
    }

    public class ReturnMenu : MenuItem
    {
        public ReturnMenu(string name) : base(name) { }
    }

    public class MenuCategory : MenuItem
    {
        public MenuItem[] Items { get; }

        public MenuCategory(string name, MenuItem[] items) : base(name)
        {
            Items = items;
        }
    }

    public class MenuApplicationStackPush : MenuItem
    {
        public Action Action { get; }

        public MenuApplicationStackPush(string name, Action action) : base(name)
        {
            Action = action;
        }
    }
```

И также есть класс `Stack`

```
public class Stack<T> 
    {
        private class ListNode<T>
        {
            private ListNode<T> next;
            private T item;
            public ListNode<T> Next
            {
                get { return next; }
                set { next = value; }
            }
            public T Item
            {
                get { return item; }
                set { item = value; }
            }

            public ListNode(T item)
            : this(item, null)
            {
            }
            public ListNode(T item, ListNode<T> next)
            {
                this.item = item;
                this.next = next;
            }
        }

        private ListNode<T> tail;
        public int Count { get; private set; }
        public void Push(T value)
        {
            tail = new ListNode<T>(value, tail);
            Count++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Pushed {value}");
        }
        public T Pop()
        {
            if (tail == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Стек пуст, нечего извлекать.");
            var node = tail;
            tail = tail.Next;
            Count--;
            Console.WriteLine($"Poped {node.Item}");
            return node.Item;
        }
    }
```

Мне бы хотелось вызывать методы из этого стека в своем меню. Реализуя вот так:

```
public class MainMenu
    {
        static DynamicStructure.Core.Stack.Stack<string> stack = new DynamicStructure.Core.Stack.Stack<string>();

        public static MenuCategory mainMenu = new MenuCategory("Главное меню", new MenuItem[]
            {
                new MenuCategory("Stack",new MenuItem[]
                {
                    new MenuApplicationStackPush("Положить данные в стек",stack.Push), //error
                    new ReturnMenu("Вернуться назад")
                }),
                new ReturnMenu("Выход")
            });
    }
```

Но получаю ошибку, пытался переписать логику классов, но начинаю менять в одном месте, ломается в другом и не могу добиться корректной работы из-за этого.

И добавлю место где вызывается сам `Action`

```
case MenuApplicationStackPush executeAction:
                                executeAction.Action();
                                ReturnToMainMenu(index);
                                break;
```

В идеале хотелось бы иметь возможность примерно такой логики вызова метода `Push`

```
DynamicStructure.Core.Stack.Stack<string> stack = new DynamicStructure.Core.Stack.Stack<string>();
 var value = Console.ReadLine();
                int num;
                bool isNum = int.TryParse(value, out num);
                if (isNum)
                    stack.Push(num.ToString());
                else
                    stack.Push(value);
```

Comment: github.com/IlyaKvashnin/DynamicStructures/tree/stack На всякий случай прикладываю ссылку на репозиторий

Comment: у вас же метод Push принимает параметр, а вы его пытаетесь сохранить в делегат без оных

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как переписать можно его переписать?

Comment: `public Action<Core.Stack.Stack<string>> Action { get; }` так пытался изменить в классе, но не помогает

Comment: Параметр у метода Push какого типа? А вы что у `Action<>` написали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить метод в `MainMenu`.

```
private void PushItem()
{
    var value = Console.ReadLine();
    stack.Push(value);
    Console.WriteLine($"Pushed {value}");
}
```

```
new MenuApplicationStackPush("Положить данные в стек", PushItem),
```

И уберите из класса стека лишнее.

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под `лишнее`?

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin вывод в консоль

Comment: Помимо стека будет еще очередь и списки с примерно 15-ю методами, мне каждый раз добавлять метод? Но вообще можно вынести эту логику в отдельный класс

Comment: Но мне нужен вывод в консоль, это идет как часть задания

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin коллекция должна быть колекцией, а не кухонным комбаином, который умеет шнурки завязыать. Я вам показал, где сделать ввод и вывод в консоль.

Comment: А, вы имеете в виду перенести вывод в `PushItem`. Да, теперь понял, исправлю

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin верно. Не усложняйте код.

Comment: Возможно вы это и ответили к моему прошлому вопросу, но уточню. Будет ли правильно, если я создам класс что-то вроде `StackPrintLogic`, там инициализирую сам `stack` и добавлю туда все методы по типу `PushItem`, а затем по этому же принципу будет `QueuePrintLogic`

Comment: Просто класс `MenuItem` довольно сильно разрастается в таком случае и хотелось бы иметь правильный подход, хоть это и сложно. И как мне кажется, в дальнейшем все-таки я буду вынужден добавить метод, который будет принимать параметры, например `PushItem(string str)`, это возможно?

Comment: Хотя, скорее всего, я ошибаюсь и может все-таки такой нужды не должно возникнуть.

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin в первую очередь избавляйтесь от статики. Как вы разместите код по классам - вам решать, я всего-лишь дал совет. Хотите знать правила, читайте про принципы SOLID. Решение помогло?

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо, хорошо, надеюсь дальше смогу разобраться)